# How can a custom list be created using Quarto in RStudio?

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, quarto

I'm trying to write a custom list in Quarto, which should be numbered like that:

d.1) First item

d.2) Second item

However, the formatting should be done accordingly to numbered list, so looking like that (but with the correct numbering format):

1. First item
2. Second item

Any idea how I can achieve that?

I really appreciate your help!

Here a reproducible example:

```
---
title: Title
author: Author name
abstract: |
  This is the abstract. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
keywords: 
  - keyword1
  - keyword2
date: last-modified
format:
  elsevier-pdf:
    keep-tex: true
    journal:
      name: Name of the journal
      formatting: preprint
      model: 3p
      cite-style: authoryear
editor: 
  markdown: 
    wrap: 72
---

# Header

Some random text.

a) First item of a normal, alphabetic list
a) Second item of this list
a) The list is still longer

Other random text.

## Header 2

Some words about this new section.

d.1) First item of the custom list

d.2) Second item of the custom list

And let's finish with some useless text.
```

Best regards,

Gary

Comment: I think you may need to rely on latex enumerate or itemize environment listing since you can't customize much the markdown listing, especially when creating a pdf output.