# How to create lists with custom listing symbol in Quarto markdown?

Tags: markdown, quarto

I have a very similar question to this one:
[How can a custom list be created using Quarto in RStudio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73946057/how-can-a-custom-list-be-created-using-quarto-in-rstudio)

Is there any option to customize the listing symbol for all elements in the list (I dont need automatic numeration or letters)?

Let's say I want all elements wo be listed after a `+`

```
+ first
+ second
+ third
```

with quarto will generate the same as stackoverflow markdown:

- first
- second
- third

Answer (score 2):

For HTML you can use the [list-style-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type?retiredLocale=de) css property:

```
---
format: html
---

<style type="text/css">
    ul { list-style-type: "\1F44D"; }
</style>


+ first
+ second
+ third
```

[image]

**Edit**:

```
---
format: html
---

<style type="text/css">
    ul { list-style-type: "\1F44D"; }
    ul > li:nth-child(2) { list-style-type: "\1F44E"; }
    ul > li:nth-child(3) { list-style-type: "\1F44E"; }

</style>


+ first
+ second
+ third
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, this works for the entire list and for all lists in the document. But what if I want to customize entries within the list? Let's say -first, second, third

Comment: I make an edit.

Comment: Ok thanks, I know with css we can customize endless. But it seems the answer is that there is no simple way to customize generic lists with quarto markdown